# Magento Retail Store and Wholesale with Different Prices

Tags: magento

Hey I was wondering about magento Retail/Wholesale capabilities.

The main store will be for normal customers (retail) and they see normal prices but for wholesalers they need to login and see wholesale prices?

I don't want normal visitors to see wholesale prices.

Is that possible?

Comment: Assign customer groups to wholesalers and set special wholesale price for them

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But upon signing up how can I differentiate if this customer signing up as a wholesaler or retailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign product price as customer groups after that use this code on list or view page, you will see product different price on both side same and equal to admin price.

```
<?php  $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

 if($groupId ==1 || $groupId ==""){?>

              <?php if($product->getSpecialPrice()){?>

             <?php echo "$".$rprice = number_format($product->getPrice(),2); ?> </div>

              <?php }else{?>

              <?php  $product->setCustomerGroupId($groupId); 

           echo "$".$price = number_format($product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice(1, $product),2); ?>

              <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <?php if($product->getSpecialPrice()){ echo "Special Price $".number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(),2);?>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php }else{echo "$".$price = number_format($product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice(1, $product),2); }

 ?>  

for create customer group check this link:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customer-groups
```